# AppleScript for Netflix: Apple Event Handler Failed

Tags: applescript

I'm writing an AppleScript that would launch Netflix in an app-like manner. It checks if Netflix is open in any tab, and if it is, it will "activate" that window (focus on it) and then sets it to the Netflix tab. If Netflix is not open, it will open it in a new window.

I am getting a strange error: "Apple Event Handler Failed". What is causing this error?

Here is the full code:

```
set netflixIsOpen to false
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of windows)
        repeat with j from 1 to (count of (tabs of window i))
            set theURL to URL of tab j of window i
            if theURL contains ".netflix.com/" then
                -- display dialog "netflix found!"
                set netflixIsOpen to true
                set miniaturized of window i to false
                activate window i
                tell window i
                    set current tab to tab j
                    -- if not logged in, then go to the homepage
                    if theURL does not contain "movies.netflix.com/" then
                        set URL of tab j to "http://movies.netflix.com/WiHome"
                    end if
                end tell
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    if not netflixIsOpen then
        make new document with properties {URL:"http://movies.netflix.com/WiHome"}
    end if
end tell
```

**Edit:** The error focus on "(count of (tabs of window i))".

Here is the debug:

```
    count every tab of window 2
        --> error number -10000
Result:
error "Safari got an error: AppleEvent handler failed." number -10000
```

There was only one window open. It seems as though AppleScript is always counting one extra window. Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Your exit repeat is breaking out of the tab loop, but not the window loop.  So I do not think that is doing what you think it should.  I would recommend changing the logic to something like while loop instead of for loops, or to just add the exit clause around the whole inner loop

```
repeat with j from 1 to (count of (tabs of window i))
   if not netflixIsOpen then
     ....
```

Like that, then, even tho the loops will continue, it will not call the code twice.

Comment: Good observation, but that wasn't the problem. It seems as though Safari didn't have enough time to launch, so I put in a delay of 2 seconds using "delay 2"

Comment: Abdulla, Where did you put the delay 2 ?? I am curious because I am getting a similar error: 
`netflix.scpt:182:209: execution error: Safari got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000) `